# Why in std::condition_variable notify_all works faster than notify_one (on random requests)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, condition-variable

I wrote my implementation of *std::shared_mutex*, but on my tests it worked for several minutes, replaced **notify_one** with **notify_all**, it began to work for 20 milliseconds. This is because of the overhead of waking up exactly one conditional variable, why it works more slowly than that **notify_all**.

```
class RWLock {
public:
    template <class Func>
    void Read(Func func) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        no_writer_.wait(lock, [this] { return !write_; });
        ++read_cnt_;
        lock.unlock();

        try {
            func();
        } catch (...) {
            End();
            throw;
        }
        End();
    }

    template <class Func>
    void Write(Func func) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        no_readers_.wait(lock, [this] { return read_cnt_ == 0; });

        write_ = true;
        try {
            func();
        } catch (...) {
            write_ = false;
            throw;
        }

        write_ = false;

        no_writer_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable no_writer_;
    std::condition_variable no_readers_;
    int read_cnt_ = 0;
    bool write_ = false;

    void End() {
        mutex_.lock();
        --read_cnt_;
        no_readers_.notify_all();
        mutex_.unlock();
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can understand better the issue.

Comment: Also there's a `shared_mutex` in the standard library, you don't need to implement your own rwlock.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov the question starts with "I wrote my implementation of std::shared_mutex".

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Are you building your code with optimisations enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You signal the condition while the mutex locked.

There is a common optimization you may like to try: release the mutex before calling `notify_one`/`notify_all`.

Comment: Sounds rather like a comment than an answer. *Will* that optimisation solve the problem? Then answer, but unlucky wording. Otherwise (really just a try) should be a comment.